# Maven : Migrating Android project from Ant to Maven

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea, android-maven-plugin

I started an Android project, and by default it is built with ANT, I am trying to upgrade it to Maven so I can get rid of compile time problems I am having with Android SDK, and ease of library import and management. The problems I have encountered are :

1) How to modify build.xml to instruct it to use maven.
2) Maven complaining folder structure is wrong.

Here is my build.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="myapp" default="help">
 <property file="local.properties"/>
    <property file="ant.properties"/>
<property environment="env"/>
    <condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
        <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME"/>
    </condition>
// and more
```

So I presume I have to modify the ant.properties attribute, how can I suggest to use Maven??

Here is the POM.xml I have pasted in the Parent directory of the project, but when I try to run mvn compile, I get the following error :

```
Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:4.0.0-rc.2:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project gs-maven-android:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Found files or folders in non-standard locations in the project!
[ERROR] ....This might be a side-effect of a migration to Android Maven Plugin 4+.
[ERROR] ....Please observe the warnings for specific files and folders above.
[ERROR] ....Ideally you should restructure your project.
[ERROR] ....Alternatively add explicit configuration overrides for files or folders.
[ERROR] ....Finally you could set failOnNonStandardStructure to false, potentially resulting in other failures.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

And finally, here is the POM.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.hello</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyAPP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-rc.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>20</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

So what am I doing wrong here? Any help would be nice. I am using Intellij Idea on Ubuntu Linux. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please update to a full release version and then update the error message in the post. The latest release is 4.3.0.

The warning is about the source code and other sources being located in non-standard folders. You should use the standard structure. The full version will show error message with details where everything should be.